# Can we have codereview.stackexchange's smaller prettify font size on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Over the past few days I've been perusing the new [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site that's recently entered the beta phase.

One of the things that struck me immediately was the smaller code prettifier font size. Can we have the same font size on Stack Overflow?

Code samples on the Code Review site seem much more readable than code samples on the Stack Overflow site. I find our present font size makes it sometimes unavoidable to end up with horizontal scrollbars thus forcing lines of code to have to span multiple lines. This is especially true if there's more than a couple of block indentations.

A slightly smaller font would solve this problem for a sizeable number of cases.

Comment: Donning flameproof underwear...:)

Comment: For reference: SO and CR.se both use 14px for proportional and monospaced fonts in the body of posts.  SO also uses 14px for code blocks but CR.se uses 12px for code blocks.

Comment: @Kev, I'd rather scroll than squint to be honest ... sorry, but -1.

Comment: -1, all code should be precisely 79 characters wide.

Comment: +1: death to the hated horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I very much agree. But I also use a font size of <= 8 in my editor, which is apparently quite unusual. There have to be *some* advantages to being young, I suppose.

Comment: @cody - I'm the same as you (and I'm no spring chicken). And that's on a 1920x1200 panel as well. The present font is a bit Fisher-Price :)

Comment: +1 would +1 again.  I likes, I likes.

Answer (score 4):

1. Code Review is supposed to have *bigger code blocks* than the rest, justifying the smaller font size. (I don't think it's a good idea, because you're supposed to read the code, so why make it uncomfortably small.)
2. On Code Review, I have to zoom in to decently read the code. Don't make me do that elsewhere.

Comment: +1 - I'm having some sight problems (just from getting older) and I'm still in the process of finding just the right prescription / reading combination to work comfortably. SO is one of the few sites I can read without a problem, with or without glasses. I'd hate to see any major changes. Granted, I do have control over my own settings, but it seems a shame to have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I do not agree, on the code review site you are obviously expecting to copy/paste and perhaps then use your tools of choice to help "review"

that is not the same as "reading" a smaller amount of code, don't make it more difficult for the other questions is what I say! I can scan code (at biggish size) to pinpoint a <strike>larger</strike> broader issue - and if I want to review code for smaller issues then I'll go copy/paste from a "review" question site..