# Suggest modifying the site CSS to allow more than 80 characters in a code example without h-scrolling

Tags: feature-request

The 80 character per line rule is ancient and almost everyone just ignores it whenever it's convenient to.

I have a script I wanted to post as an example, but it looks like crap on SO, so I posted it as a Gist and linked to it. I would have just rewritten the code to make it fit, but it becomes much less readable.

If GitHub do this, SO could.

P.S. If you're interested, it's [this script](https://gist.github.com/carlsmith/5673832).

Comment: Code Review has a smaller font.  We've floated the idea of using the same font on Stack Overflow, but it's never gotten much traction.

Comment: @Robert ooh, I do like the font on code review much better. FWIW, Droid Sans Mono 12px is also the font used on [dba.SE].

Comment: @RobertHarvey Were there any objections?

Comment: @CarlSmith: No, but I guess it wasn't compelling enough.  I've worked with designers before; they don't like you moving their cheese unless there's a really good reason, because all of the elements that a designer puts into a web page have to work together harmoniously. (**Boss:** Can you make that label fuschia?  **Designer:** AAAARRRGGGGHHH!)

Comment: Fair enough. I'm liking the pop out window idea suggested in the thread Aaron linked to below.

Comment: @CarlSmith the pop out window will be a disaster in cases where there are many independent code snippets in a post and, say, you want to compare two of them. Will there be a single pop out window that gets its contents replaced every time you try to inspect a different code sample? Will you now have many windows to manage? How will this work on mobile?

Comment: [80 characters ought to be enough for anybody.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bill_Gates) Please also have pity for us working in cramped rooms on old VAXes.

Comment: @DeerHunter But then people started to use C++ templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were lots of duplicates pointed out in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187920/allow-code-snippets-to-use-more-screen-width/), asked last night.

One of them in particular [showed some workarounds you can try out for yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout); I haven't tried them, but they may already work in SO better than the one you wrote.

Comment: Thanks, I did do a quick search. I'll follow that thread. Can you close this please?